# Merge 2 csv file based on 1 column and value of the other group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, merge

I want to merge two csv file based on date, but I want to put the value of the second file's columns in front of related value in column 'type' in the first file.

this an example of what I want:

first data:

```
data = {'type': ['a', 'a','b','b', 'c', 'd'],
        'Date': ['2007-05-10', '1996-05-01', 
                 '1996-05-01','1996-02-02', 
                 '1996-02-02','1990-01-05']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  type  Date
0   a   2007-05-10
1   a   1996-05-01
2   a   1996-05-01
3   b   1996-02-02
4   c   1996-02-02
5   d   1990-01-05
```

the second data:

```
data2 = {'Date': ['2007-05-10', '1996-05-01','1996-05-01','1996-02-02', '1996-02-02','1990-01-05'], 
        'a': [2,3,5,6,7,9], 'b':[4,7,7,6,6,2], 'c':[1,3,5,4, 4,'NAN'], 'd': [2,3,5,7,9,'NAN']}  

dc = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

```
      Date      a   b   c   d
0   2007-05-10  2   4   1   2
1   1996-05-01  3   7   3   3
2   1996-05-01  5   7   5   5
3   1996-02-02  6   6   4   7
4   1996-02-02  7   6   4   9
5   1990-01-05  9   2   NAN NAN
```

The out put should be:

```
  type    Date      rate
0   a   2007-05-10  2
1   a   1996-05-01  3
2   b   1996-05-01  7
3   b   1996-02-02  6
4   c   1996-02-02  4
5   d   1990-01-05  NAN
```

How can I merge these csv files to acheive the above output?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) on the second dataframe `dc` to bring it to a shape with which you can do a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with the first dataframe `df`.

```
df.merge(
     pd.melt(dc, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
     var_name = 'type', value_name = 'rate'), on = ['type', 
     'Date']).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output:

```
  type    Date    rate
0   a   2007-05-10  2
1   a   1996-05-01  3
2   a   1996-05-01  5
3   b   1996-05-01  7
4   b   1996-02-02  6
5   c   1996-02-02  4
6   d   1990-01-05  NAN
```

Now you see that it identifies three rows of `a` in the merge which it should IMO because there are 3 matching rows in `df` and `dc`.

But if your intention is to remove duplicates based on `['type', 'Date']` then you can always do [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `subset` option.

With drop_duplicates on subset it will look :

```
df.merge(
   pd.melt(dc, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
   var_name = 'type', value_name = 'rate'), on = ['type', 
  'Date']).drop_duplicates(subset = ['type', 'Date']).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output:

```
  type    Date    rate
0   a   2007-05-10  2
1   a   1996-05-01  3
2   b   1996-05-01  7
3   b   1996-02-02  6
4   c   1996-02-02  4
5   d   1990-01-05  NAN
```

Comment: Thank you, it kind of work. I used the first script, but why it drops a lot of rows( also without drop function)?

Comment: I used: `df.merge(
     pd.melt(dc, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
     var_name = 'type', value_name = 'rate'), on = ['type', 
     'Date'])`

Comment: With the data in the question you asked, I get 9 rows without drop_duplicates in the first script. How many rows you get?

Comment: In the data in the question, me too, but In the main data that I have 1000 rows dropped. I guess if there is no matching value it will drop from the main data instead of putting NA on the merged data. right?

Comment: If you want the main data on the left dataframe you could use `how = 'left'` in your merge.